# Android FFmpegFrameRecorder crashing

Tags: android, javacv

**Hello guys,**

Here is my code:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)
            ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();

    screenWidth = display.getWidth();
    screenHeight = display.getHeight();

    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "init recorder");
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "ffmpeg_url: " + file);
    recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(file, imageWidth,
            imageHeight, 1);
    recorder.setFormat("flv");
    recorder.setSampleRate(AudioRateInHz);
    recorder.setFrameRate(frameRate);

    audioRecordRunnable = new AudioRecordRunnable();
    audioThread = new Thread(audioRecordRunnable);
```

When i'm trying to run it on my Android activity, i got this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jniavformat from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/xx.app.android-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/xx.app.android-2]: findLibrary returned null

The line of the exception shows me that it's occurred on this line:

`new FFmpegFrameRecorder(file, imageWidth, imageHeight, 1);`

Any ideas what this exception means?

Comment: It means the library named 'jniavformat' couldn't be loaded. Your project must be set up incorrectly. Native libraries such as jniavformat must be in a 'libs/<arch>' subfolder of your project.

Comment: Thanks Reuben, i will try to add thid library in the correct way